# Black screen after login on Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: linux-mint, x11, xorg, radeon

I cannot use Cinnamon on a computer which has Linux Mint 19.3 installed.

When I start the computer, `lightdm` starts, I can enter my password, but then the login doesn't work as I can only see the mouse cursor and the wallpaper.

If I boot Linux with the `nomodeset` option, I just have a blinking cursor after the boot logo, and I cannot access the terminal with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

Video Card: Radeon Mobility X1700

/etc/X11/xorg.conf file:
http://termbin.com/r0vfm
/var/log/Xorg.log.0 file:
http://termbin.com/1val

How can I solve this?